# checkout page field rename in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label

I am trying to rename the field text on checkout page `woocommerce` this is the code which i am using.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );


function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Address (No PO Boxes)';

     return $fields;
}
```

Now what the issue is while uploading page `Address (No PO Boxes)` is showing but the page load fully it start shows Address again i am confused why it is showing like that

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer i update the label in `woocommerce/includes/class-ec-countries.php`. There you can see the code on `line no.509` code will be in array

```
'address_1' => array(
            'label'       => __( 'Address', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => _x( 'Street address', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'    => true,
            'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' )
        ),
```

i changes the Address with my required text and it is now working awesome